# Next.js project deployed on firebase and the content fetched from sanity

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, sanity

I have a project deployed on firebase and the content from sanity and this is the code of fetching the data from sanity

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const sliderQuery = '*[_type == "homeslider"] | order(order)';
  const homeslider = await client.fetch(sliderQuery);

  const aboutusQuery = '*[_type == "aboutus"] | order(order)';
  const aboutus = await client.fetch(aboutusQuery);

  const aboutuslistQuery = '*[_type == "aboutuslist"] | order(order)';
  const aboutuslist = await client.fetch(aboutuslistQuery);

  const whyusQuery = '*[_type == "whyus"] | order(order)';
  const whyus = await client.fetch(whyusQuery);

  const whyuslistQuery = '*[_type == "whyuslist"] | order(order)';
  const whyuslist = await client.fetch(whyuslistQuery);

  return {
    props: { homeslider, aboutus, aboutuslist, whyus, whyuslist },
  };
};
```

and everything works fine on the dev mode but on production everytime i try to change something on sanity it doesnt reflect on the live site and i have to re build and deploy again

so i tried to add firebase functions and here is the code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
db.settings(settings);
exports.sanityWebhookHandler = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.projectId !== "MY_PROJECT_ID") {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
  try {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    await getSanityData(req.body);
    await triggerRebuild();
    res.status(200).send();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});

const getSanityData = async (body) => {
  console.log("Setting up client", body.projectId);

  for (const id of body.ids.all) {
    const url = `https://${body.projectId}.api.sanity.io/v1/data/query/${body.dataset}?query=*[_id%20==%20$id]&$id=%22${id}%22`;
    console.log(url);
    const resp = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    const { result } = resp;

    for (const item of result) {
      console.log("Updating", `${item._type}/${item._id}`);
      await db
        .doc(`sanity/docs/${item._type}/${item._id}`)
        .set(item, { merge: true });
    }
  }
};

const triggerRebuild = async () => {
  const url = `https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/sites/MY_SITE_NAME/versions?parent=projects/MY_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID`;
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${functions.config().firebase.token}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      config: {},
    }),
  };
  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to trigger rebuild: ${response.status}`);
  }
};
```

and then i ran `firebase deploy --only functions` command and i got the URL from firebase functions on the site and added it to sanity webhooks, but still nothing works. can anyone help me please and tell me what i miss or what's wrong?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour when using `getStaticProps`. Either use `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` with [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration).